# Cloud Spanner order without ORDER BY

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

If I don’t specify ORDER BY in a query to Cloud Spanner, will rows always be returned to me in primary key (or index) order? My tests seem to indicate that this always happens, but I want to be sure.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no ORDER BY in the query then no ordering guarantee is provided and you should not rely on any assumption of ordering in the result. Even if you observe the desired ordering in practice - it might change in the future.